# cant iterate over JSON with typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I've got a JSON document with different field names (27_sourcename0, 27_sourcename1 ...).
To check if the field name exists, I created a field name array (this.sourcenames27).

So I want to check if the field name exists to get the value "image.jpg".

```
this.document = { 
  _source: {
             ID: "55",
             27_sourcename0: "image.jpg"
             27_sourcename1: "image.jpg"
           }
}


this.sourcenames27 = [
      {
        sourceName: '27_sourcename0',
      },
      {
        sourceName: '27_sourcename1',
      },
      {
        sourceName: '27_sourcename2',
      },
]

//this doesnt work
for (let item of this.sourcenames27) {
console.log(this.document['_source'] + item.sourceName);
   if (this.document['_source'] + item.sourceName) {
      console.log('jeah it exists');
   }
}

// this works well
console.log(this.document['_source']['27_sourcename1']
```

I am getting the value when i use

```
this.document['_source']['27_sourcename1']
```

But I can't get the value when I iterate over the this.sourcenames27 array.
What do I overlook here?

Expected Output:
image.jpg,
image.jpg

Comment: `this.document['_source']` resolves to an object, that has three keys in in.  Performing a `+` against an object doesn't make sense.  You have to do the `[variable]` access if you are trying to dynamically access a property off of an object.  The fact that you are iterating isn't the main issue here.  It is you are misunderstanding object access in the form that is not working

Comment: `this.document['_source'][item.sourceName]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access like `this.document['_source'][item.sourceName]`, not with + operator, you are try to do like {} + string type.

```
this.document = { 
    _source: {
        ID: "55",
        27_sourcename0: "image.jpg"
        27_sourcename1: "image.jpg"
    }
  }
    
  this.sourcenames27 = [
        {
          sourceName: '27_sourcename0',
        },
        {
          sourceName: '27_sourcename1',
        },
        {
          sourceName: '27_sourcename2',
        },
  ]
  
 
  for (let item of this.sourcenames27) {
    console.log(this.document['_source'][item.sourceName]); //Note here
     if (this.document['_source'][item.sourceName]) { // Note here
        console.log('jeah it exists');
     }
  }
  
  // this works well
  console.log(this.document['_source']['27_sourcename1']
```